# use @using namspce in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I add namespace to razor and use in jquery but it's error: 
 **The name 'nameGroupNews' does not exist in the current context**

Here is code:

@using TestDA.Common
.........

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#name-group').change(function () {
           var nameGroupNews = $('#name-group').val();
           var lug = @CreateSlug.GenerateSlug(nameGroupNews);
            $('#slug-group').val = slug;
        });
    });
```

Please help me.

Comment: Try by adding your namespace in views web config file.

Comment: it does not get variable "nameGroupNews" declared. Why?

Comment: Is 'nameGroupNews' a c# code object? Are you trying to cast a DOM element to a c# Code object? Javascript and c# can not inter-op with each other. You would need to create 'nameGroupNews' object in javascript and create it in javascript.

Comment: As far as I see, `nameGroupNews` is a JS variable - **not** C# variable, hence it is impossible to use JS variable in C# context. However you can pass a JS variable content (value) into a model through AJAX callback, then using its value in C# variable.

Comment: Tetsuya Yamamoto , yes, I use ajax and it works.
Thanks for help.

Comment: post your answer and mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ajax and return value slug, it works as per below:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#name-group').change(function () {
                var name = $('#name-group').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@(Url.Action("Slug", "GroupNews"))",
                    data: { nameGroupNews: name },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#slug-group').val(data);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {

                    }



                });
            });
        });
        //
    </script>
```

In Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Slug(string nameGroupNews)
        {
            GroupNewsManager GNM = new GroupNewsManager();
            string slug = CreateSlug.GenerateSlug(nameGroupNews);
            return Json(slug);
        }
```

if you have any other suggestion, please comment.